# If you press anywhere on the screen, it displays the message

Tags: python

First and foremost, this isn't my code.(Just in case I need to say this.)
I copied this code to understand how pygame works, however, the code should only print 'Hello' when you press the button, and the code prints the message if you press anywhere on the window created. Copy the code to see what I mean.

```
win = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))

class button():
    def __init__(self, color, x,y,width,height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

def draw(self,win,outline=None):
    #Call this method to draw the button on the screen
    if outline:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, outline, (self.x-2,self.y-2,self.width+4,self.height+4),0)
        
    pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height),0)

def isOver(self, pos):
    #Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
    if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
        if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
            return True

    return False

def redrawWindow():
     win.fill((255,255,255))
     greenButton.draw(win, (0,0,0))

run = True
greenButton = button((0,255,0), 150, 225, 250, 200, 'click me :')
while run:
     pygame.mixer.init()
     redrawWindow()
     pygame.display.update()

 for event in pygame.event.get():
      pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           run = False
           pygame.quit()
           quit()

      if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
           if greenButton.isOver:
                print('Hello')

      if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
           if greenButton.isOver(pos):
                greenButton.color = (255,0,0)
           else:
                greenButton.color = (0,255,0)
```

The isOver funstion should be working, but it doesn't. Anyone see the problem in the code?

Comment: _Anyone see the problem in the code?_ Can you be more specific? Have you done any debugging yourself? _Copy the code to see what I mean._ I don't believe that's a [mcve].

Comment: well there isn't an error, but when I run the code, I should only be able to see the message 'Hello', displayed in lines `if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
           if greenButton.isOver:
                print('Hello')`

Comment: only if my cursor is over the button. However, I see the message displayed if I press anywhere in the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed a parameter in one line. Here's the new code.

```
win = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))

class button():
    def __init__(self, color, x,y,width,height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

def draw(self,win,outline=None):
    #Call this method to draw the button on the screen
    if outline:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, outline, (self.x-2,self.y-2,self.width+4,self.height+4),0)
        
    pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height),0)

def isOver(self, pos):
    #Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
    if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
        if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
            return True

    return False

def redrawWindow():
     win.fill((255,255,255))
     greenButton.draw(win, (0,0,0))

run = True
greenButton = button((0,255,0), 150, 225, 250, 200, 'click me :')
while run:
     pygame.mixer.init()
     redrawWindow()
     pygame.display.update()

 for event in pygame.event.get():
      pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           run = False
           pygame.quit()
           quit()

      if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
           if greenButton.isOver(pos): #this is the line you missed arguments in
                print('Hello')

      if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
           if greenButton.isOver(pos):
                greenButton.color = (255,0,0)
           else:
                greenButton.color = (0,255,0)
```

Please be aware I didn't test it because I didn't know what imports you made. I believe that due to lack of arguments your isOver function always returned true.

Comment: I added these imports:
import pygame
import sys